# Using one of the parameter's getter to set the value of another parameter in a C++ function?

Tags: c++, function, parameters

In a C++ function, can  I use one of the parameter's getter to set the default value of the other parameter following it? For example if I have the followig class Foo,

```
class Foo{
   public:
      setID();
      getID();
   private:
      string id;
}
```

Can I write a function fooManipulator like this,

```
int fooManipulator(Foo bar, string id = bar.getId());
```

Comment: Also, make a practice to pass structure by reference (if the pass by value is not needed). i.e. `(Foo &bar, string &id)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, as has been stated, the order of evaluation of arguments to a function is unspecified.

However, you can achieve the effect easily with an overload like this:

```
int fooManipulator(Foo bar)
{
    return fooManipulator(bar, bar.getId());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No.  You cannot refer to another parameter in a default argument because the order of evaluation of function arguments is unspecified.

For example, in your `fooManipulator` function, the argument passed to parameter `id` may be evaluated before the argument passed to parameter `bar`.  This could make invalid the use of `bar` in the default argument for parameter `id`.

Comment: Shouldn't it always be left to right evaluation ? Because, if this program compiles then it ensures that, `bar` should be declared first before used (i.e. `bar.getId()`).

Comment: @iammilind:  Parameters come into scope in left-to-right order, so yes, were `= bar.getId()` allowed, `bar` would indeed refer to the parameter `bar`.  _Arguments_ are evaluated in an unspecified order.  Given `fooManipulator(x, y)`, it is unspecified whether `x` or `y` is evaluated first.

Comment: This bitten me alot of times: `int i = 0; printf("%d, %d", ++i, ++i);` on some compilers its 0, 1 and on some it's 1, 0 and on some it depends on the compilers mood.